# how do I pass ref to state?

Tags: react-native, redux, reference

I created a ref and passed it to the component as an argument. Now how can I write it to State without dispatch?

```js
const myRef = createRef<any>();

const KeyboardAvoidingWrapper: React.FC<IKeyboardAvoidingProps> = (
  props: IKeyboardAvoidingProps,
 => {
  if (isAndroid) {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref={myRef} style={styles.scroll} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollContent}>
        <KeyboardAvoiding>{props.children}</KeyboardAvoiding>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Comment: why do you want to put a `ref` in state?

Comment: the question is that I need to create a ref in this functional component, pass it as an argument to the component, and get this ref in General in another component. How can this be done?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass this whole "parent ref" into your "props.children". Depending if you are using React 16, there is React Context that you can use <Provider> to wrap outside of ScrollView to consume via <Consumer> in your children. But if, you want to use Redux...I have no good comments though i understand that another Store wrapping on this.

Comment: To add another cleaner approach, if both components does not share...I suggest you create a Container that wraps both components(your General and this component), your can pass you reference on this container <ContinerX><General/><KeyboardAvoidWrapper/></ContainerX>. Sorry if too much words, but trying to open up more general solutions for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you.

```
<Component ref={(ref) => {
  // You can now write ref to state,
  // which I will not recommend
  // or pass it to callback
  props.getInnerRef(ref);
}} />

// You need to pass getInnerRef
<Component getInnerRef={(ref) => {
  this.innerRef = ref;
}}
```

Comment: the question is that I need to create a ref in this functional component, pass it as an argument to the component, and get this ref in General in another component. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref} className="FancyButton">
    {props.children}
  </button>
));

// You can now get a ref directly to the DOM button:
const ref = React.createRef();
<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>;
```

Please refer the react documentation. It clearly defines how to use refs.

[ForwadingRefs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)